# How can I list IIS working processes programmatically?

Tags: c#, .net, iis, windows-7, wmi

I've tried using the WorkerProcess class as suggested [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771273(v=ws.10).aspx), but getting a "System.Management.ManagementException: Invalid class" error message.

```
        var scope = new ManagementScope("//./root/CIMV2");
        var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM WorkerProcess"));
```

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this for IIS 7+ then you can easily use ServerManager for that you can find some examples here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosag/archive/2006/04/17/microsoftwebadministration.aspx

For WorkerProcesses, you can do:

```
using(ServerManager iisManager = new ServerManager()) {
  foreach(WorkerProcess w3wp in iisManager.WorkerProcesses) {
    Console.WriteLine("W3WP ({0})", w3wp.ProcessId);

    foreach (Request request in w3wp.GetRequests(0)) {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1},{2},{3}",
                    request.Url,
                    request.ClientIPAddr,
                    request.TimeElapsed,
                    request.TimeInState);
    }
  }
}
```